# No photo available on production in django application

Tags: python, django, image, templates, static

I did the command git pull on my production server. I downloaded my latest changes, which was to put the photo on the home page.
Rebooted: supervisorctl restart myprocess
I do not get a picture on the main page.

Photo placed in the folder "images", which is located in the static.
My code in html:

```
<img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}">
```

Code in Firebug:

```
<img src="/static/images/logo.png">
```

Comment: What happens when you go directly to the image?  Is it loaded it or returning an error code.  You also look in the access logs of the web server.

Comment: @Ross In Firebug I get 404 Not Found status. I have not done this time the command: python manage.py collectstatic. I did it just for the first time

Comment: Are you sure your image is in the folder? Perhaps you put the code to show the image but forgot to add image to repo/upload image.

Comment: you need to do collectstatic again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You supposed to put your static files in one of your STATICFILES_DIRS not into STATIC_ROOT after that you need to do:

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

then it will be available via:

```
<img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}">
```